# How to implement a distributed system using multiple ports with Java CORBA?

Tags: java, distributed-system, corba

I have a problem of using Java CORBA. I need to implement a distributed system having 3 servers and more than 5 clients. I have done that using Java RMI and it works well, and I can easily use 3 ports by calling LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port) for 3 servers.

According to the CORBA tutorial(http://www.ejbtutorial.com/programming/tutorial-for-corba-hello-world-using-java), the target port number should be activated by running "start orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050" via terminal. However, after running this port, I am unable to activate another one. I opened a new terminal window to run a different port, it showed the following message:

com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelAcceptorImpl initialize
SEVERE: "IOP00410216: (COMM_FAILURE) Unable to create listener thread on the specified port: 1049"

I tried to google it, and it said only one listener is allowed. If it is, how is it possible to make a distributed system(localhost is sufficient enough in this project)? Using one port to communicate is unrealistic. Is there any approach to do it? Thanks.

Comment: `LocateRegistry` is part of RMI, not part of Java CORBA. Why do you think you need multiple ports?

Comment: @MarquisofLorne That's the way I did using RMI. In this project there are 3 servers, shouldn't it have 3 ports? Each server uses its port to communicate with its clients. I don't want to mess up the channels. I want to know if it is possible to activate multiple ports at the same time. If it is just allowed to have one, that's not flexible.

Comment: For CORBA you need COSNaming, not the RMI Registry. In both you can bind as many servers as you like to a single naming service. No need for extra ports.

Comment: You should also be warned that the CORBA support has been removed from J2SE as of I think Java 9 onwards, so this is probably not a path you should be pursuing.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Probably the description above is not so clear, the Registry I mentioned was for RMI. I used 3 ports for the communication and it works fine. Of course it doesn't belong to CORBA. I didn't mess up the concept.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I tried using the NamingContextExt reference name to bind the server, and it worked in this way as well, so it is acceptable. Actually I know that CORBA is becoming legacy, this is just the course project from the university. Personally I won't plan to learn it deeply. Anyway, problem solved, thanks.